# How do I use Qt in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-code

I'm using Linux Mint 18, and the Visual Studio Code marketplace doesn't list an extension for Qt.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should give a chance for this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools

With this, you can configure include paths for better IntelliSense results.

**Configuring includePath**

One way to configure e.g the QtCore module.

1. <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + p</kbd> to open command palette
2. Search for: `C/Cpp: Edit Configurations`
3. You should have a new tab called: `c_cpp_properties.json`
4. In `configurations` array you should edit the **Linux** section
5. Add your paths in the `includePath` setting e.g: `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore`

For more check this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/Getting%20started.md

**IntelliSense engines**

We recommend using the "Default" engine for the best IntelliSense experience. However, it is possible to explicitly choose the IntelliSense engine by editing your [user or workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). The setting you should modify is `C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine`

- `Default` - Visual Studio's IntelliSense engine, which is the default engine that provides semantic-aware IntelliSense features
- `Tag Parser` - the "fuzzy" IntelliSense engine that provides quick but "fuzzy" results, is used to provide the fallback experience if the default engine is

More details about it:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/IntelliSense%20engine.md

Comment: For me the path was: /opt/Qt/5.13.0/gcc_64/include/**

Comment: Yes, if you installed Qt via the provided GUI based installer the install path will be the /opt/ one AFAIK.

Comment: My path was: /usr/include/qt4/**

Answer (score 2):

You can use CMake with CMake tools extension.

Just create a CMake project in vscode and add qt framework to your project in CMakeLists.txt.

Link to the extension - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools

Use CMake with qt - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html

Answer (score 1):

The methods for adding Qt headers to the `cpptools` extension have changed since the last answer. Options for doing so now include:

1. Automatically adding a found Qt header path by clicking on the light bulb above an IntelliSense error and selecting `Add to "includePaths"...`
2. Manually adding the Qt header paths to the settings UI, from the command palette, via `C/Cpp: Edit Configurations (UI)`
3. Manually adding the Qt header paths to the settings JSON file, from the command palette, via `C/Cpp: Edit Configurations (JSON)`

More info in [this page of the new documentation.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/Getting%20started%20with%20IntelliSense%20configuration.md)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the C++ extension (cpptools) mentioned in other answers, there are also extensions for Qt Quick that add support for the QML language. The **QML Syntax/Tools** extension adds syntax highlighting, auto-completion, and also allows to run and test your Qt Quick app using QML Hot Reload: [Visual Studio Code Extension for Qt Quick](https://blog.felgo.com/develop-qt-quick-apps-with-visual-studio-code-qml-extension#vs-code-extensions-qt-qml)