# Using SFML Graphical Library with Visual Studio Code and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, sfml

I've installed SFML but Visual Studio Code can't find the library. I am really new to Ubuntu and also pretty new to C++.

How can I get my IDE to recognize the library?

Here is what "`libsfml-graphics-d.so`" displays when entered into the terminal.

```
libsfml-window-d.so.2.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libsfml-window-d.so.2.5  
libsfml-window-d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libsfml-window-d.so  
libsfml-system-d.so.2.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libsfml-system-d.so.2.5  
libsfml-system-d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libsfml-system-d.so  
libsfml-network-d.so.2.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libsfml-network-d.so.2.5    
libsfml-network-d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libsfml-network-d.so
libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5    
libsfml-graphics-d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so  
libsfml-audio-d.so.2.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.5  
libsfml-audio-d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so
```

These are my User Settings in Visual Studio Code:

```
{  
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,  
    "editor.tabSize": 3,  
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,  
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,  
    "telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false,  
   "window.zoomLevel": 1,  
    "editor.rulers": [80,120],  
   "clang.cxxflags": ["/usr/local/lib/"],  
}
```

When my mouse hovers over my C++ code, "`#include <libsfml-graphics-d.so>`" this text is displayed:

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath.
>    IntelliSense features for this translation unit (/home/userName/Desktop/Temp_Towers_Of_Babel/World_Generation/Main.cpp) will be provided by the Tag Parser.
>   Cannot open source file "libsfml-graphics-d.so"
>   'libsfml-graphics-d.so' file not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to include e.g SFML graphics why don't you try this way?

`#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>`

On the other hand, I recommend you to install "c/c++" plugin if you would like to work with C++ in VS Code. You can find it on the marketplace with this search term `c/c++`. 
[vscode-cpptools](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools)

If you can compile the example code from [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-linux.php) with g++ that is a good point.

I think CMake also help me a lot in connection with proper configuration.

e.g. This is a simple CMakeLists.txt file. [Here](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24070.0) you can read the whole article.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(SFMLTest)

## If you want to link SFML statically
# set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)

## In most cases better set in the CMake cache
# set(SFML_DIR "<sfml root prefix>/lib/cmake/SFML")

find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS graphics audio REQUIRED)
add_executable(SFMLTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SFMLTest sfml-graphics sfml-audio)
```

`whereis SFML` command may help you to find the `<sfml root prefix>` part of this line `# set(SFML_DIR "<sfml root prefix>/lib/cmake/SFML")`

### So my solution proposal step by step:

1. Install VS Code [c/c++](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools) and [CMake Tools](https://github.com/vector-of-bool/vscode-cmake-tools) plugins
2. Check you can compile the example main.cpp with g++ from [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-linux.php)
3. Add the code snipet to a `CMakeList.txt` file in the project root folder
4. Install cmake with `apt install cmake` command
5. Go to your project folder and add a build folder with `mkdir build`
6. `cd build`
7. `cmake ..`
8. `make` after this step you will get an executable named `SFMLTest`
9. Open the project folder in VS Code. I think it will configure everything by itself
10. If it is still not working, you should check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976570/how-use-qt-in-visual-studio-code/47964063#47964063) and try to configure the include path by yourself