# How to enable documentation comments for C++/Qt in VS Code?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code

Following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47964063/13994294), I have already managed to fix the IntelliSense suggestions for my C++ hello world program using Qt headers. So for instance, when I type `QString::`, the class methods `append`, `arg`, etc. are suggested correctly. However, when I choose any of them, I would expect to read a short documentation comment describing what the selected method does do. Unfortunately, this information is not available.

[image: Screenshot of IntelliSense]

I have also followed [this tip](https://askubuntu.com/a/595887/1140486) and installed `qt5-doc` on my Ubuntu system, but I have no idea how I can use the `.qch` documentation files in VS Code. Do you have any pointer for me?

Comment: are there doc strings in the header files for Qt, if not Intellisense can't show them

Comment: Nope, Qt does its documentation mostly (if not solely) in source files. So I agree with you: I think VSCode's IntelliSense won't be able to display the documentation.