# Cant find path to QtCore for C++ intellisense in VSCode on ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, qt5

*tldr: what path do I include in my VScode C++ project to use Qt on ubuntu?*

I tried this already : [How use Qt in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976570/how-use-qt-in-visual-studio-code/47964063)

Having `#include <QApplication>` in my main.cpp file in VScode, I'm getting `cannot open source file "QApplication"C/C++(1696)` pop up, and all of my Qt includes in other files have the same or similar problems.

To find my QtCore path I tried the following:
`QtCore --version`, and a number of other variations of Qt, qt, and QtCore, with no avail.

So I tried this:

```
xxxxx@xxxx:/$ qmake --version
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.15.2 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Which seems great, I need only look in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and include the appropriate sub directory in my c_cpp_properties.json file of my VScode C++ project.

But this didn't work.

I tried a number of various Qt related subdirectories here, but none of them seemed to point to the right place.

*tldr: what path do I include in my VScode C++ project to use Qt on ubuntu?*

Comment: What path did you put in `c_cpp_properties.json` I expect `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` won't work because QApplication is not in that folder.

Comment: For me on Gentoo this file is in the `/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets` folder. For Qt I expect you will want to use a recursive search in your include path so you don't have to list the 80+ folders in the qt5 include directory: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference#_configuration-properties](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference#_configuration-properties)

Comment: I've included the following directories: `                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"`, but in my `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory, there is no qt5 folder

Comment: You may want to use CMake anyways for this and the CMake extension. Qt will be difficult to work with in VSCode because you have to call moc, uic ... related to CMake: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux)

Comment: I plan on doing everything in the terminal, but it would be nice to have highlighting and my project properly including the Qt stuff

Comment: This may help figure out the correct folders: [https://serverfault.com/questions/96964/list-of-files-installed-from-apt-package](https://serverfault.com/questions/96964/list-of-files-installed-from-apt-package)